# i2cdetect detects device - Pi can't access / find it

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, i2c, sensor

Currently I'm working with a **gyro-sensor** and need to use **i2c** in order to use it. Using a Pi 3 B (os:NOOBS) on kernel: 
`Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

**I activated i2c in my config and made sure to add it to the modules as well as the tools package and python-smbus.**

So far so good. `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` -> displays a table with a '68' at column 8, row 60.

```
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
  00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

---

This means my sensor is being detected but running `sudo i2cget -y 0x68 0x68` is giving me the following error:

**Error: Could not open file "/dev/i2c-104" or "/dev/i2c/104": No such file or directory**

I suspect that I have to find the bus-adress though I've no idea what so ever.

Comment: Post your answer as an answer, not as a revision to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bus address is 1 (as in the 1 used in -y 1).

The command `sudo i2cget -y 0x68 0x68` is saying read device 0x68 on bus 0x68.

0x68 hex is 104 decimal, which is why it complains about the non-existent bus 104.

I presume you mean to enter `sudo i2cget -y 1 0x68`

Comment: question solved, I discovered the solution and it works now (see changes). Though  I will mark your solution because it explains why the error occurs, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem:

First of all read @joan 's answer for an explanation as to why the error occurs.

Secondly, run the following code: `sudo i2cget -y 1 adress` <-- adress needs to be replaced by what is in your table with the i2cdetect command as shown below!

In my case the **adress is 0x68**, the command will return something like **0x83** (my case) and that is your register.

Comment: With current versions of Raspbian you don't need `sudo` for I²C access. Stop using `sudo` when you don't need to.